# Continuar secuencia de registros de base de datos basandose en campo "orden"

Tags: oracle

Tengo una duda respecto a base de datos.

Mi problema es que no quiero que se pueda agregar un registro con un orden existente.

En su lugar quiero que se haga hueco para el nuevo registro y los demás incrementen en uno su orden para ello

Tengo una tabla en la cual contiene un campo llamado `orden` y los datos se registran 1 por 1 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,etc), pero al momento de insertar en la tabla un registro nuevo le inserto un orden 10 pero ese ya existe lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de insertar los demás registros se les sume 1 a partir del que se registró.

Por lo tanto, quisiera que ese nuevo valor de orden aumentara en 1 si es el caso, o continuara la seguencia que ya existe, es decir.

si los registros van por orden 55, y yo meto orden 55, este o la pase a 56.

Comment: Hola mazhivo, me parece que tu pregunta no es clara, se requieren detalles más específicos así como segmentos de código para poder determinar con mayor exactitud una solución a tu pregunta.

Comment: @mazhivo te van a cerrar la pregunta tras una espera de 5 días (lleva 23 horas, así que quedan 4 días). Aunque yo he entendido tu pregunta y sé cómo solucionarlo van a cerrarla si no mejoras la redacción. Bastará con agregar algo como por ejemplo: "Mi problema es que no quiero que se pueda agregar un registro con un orden existen. En su lugar quiero que se haga hueco para el nuevo registro y los demás incrementen en uno su orden para ello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo dos formas de hacerlo sin usar disparadores o procedimientos almacenados.

La primera, más sencilla y portable, es forzar la suma dentro de una transacción siempre que introduzcamos un nuevo registro:

```sql
-- START TRANSACTION no es necesario en PLSQL, se crea automáticamente una nueva
-- en la primera consulta SQL al comienzo del script o tras un COMMIT/ROLLBACK
UPDATE tabla SET orden = orden + 1 WHERE orden >= ...;
INSERT INTO tabla (...) VALUES (...);
COMMIT;
```

El problema es que, obviamente, que el valor del campo `orden` de los registros más altos subirá de forma descontrolada.

La segunda consiste en un bloque que actualice el orden sólo en caso de dar error por clave duplicada:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tabla (...) VALUES (...);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    UPDATE tabla SET orden = orden + 1 WHERE orden >= ...;
    INSERT INTO tabla (...) VALUES (...);
END;
```

En este caso deberás definir el campo `orden` como índice único.

Puedes consultar más detalles sobre la gestión de excepciones en la [documentación oficial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00703).